# I have a question about the name of my blog

Tags: subdomains, domain

I would like to have `frufinurlig.wordpress.com` as a name on my blog. It seems to be free and yet I can not get it. Why is that?

Comment: WordPress.com support can give you better explanation on this.

Answer (score 1):

https://frufinurlig.wordpress.com/ shows the message that the name "is no longer available. The authors have deleted this site."

WordPress.com does not "recycle" their user name subdomains. You need to pick another account name when you sign up at https://wordpress.com/start/survey